# Delay qTip From Closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

How can I delay the qTip2 plugin from closing, so that a user can click on a link within the tooltip? I want to having links to social networks when you hover over my e-mail address on my website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the hide.fixed and hide.delay properties in the documentation:

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/hide/#fixed

> hide.fixed: When set to true, the tooltip will not hide if moused
>   over, allowing the contents to be clicked and interacted with.
>   Note: Adding a hide delay is generally done when this is enabled to
>   give the user time to mouseover the tooltip before hiding.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/hide/#delay

> hide.delay: Time in milliseconds by which to delay hiding of the
>   tooltip when the hide.event is triggered on the hide.target

```
$('.selector').qtip({
   content: {
      text: $('<a href="http://google.com">Visit Google</a>'),
   },
   hide: {
      fixed: true, // Let the user mouse into the tip
      delay: 500 // Don't hide right away so that they can mouse into it
   }
});
```

Comment: Ahh! Thanks, I'll give that a try as soon as I can. I couldn't find that anywhere in the documentation.